# dyld: Library not loaded different behavior for 6.0 simulator/6.0 device

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6, dyld, ios-frameworks

My app runs fine on the iPhone 6.0 Simulator in Xcode, but when I try to run it on my 6.0 device, I get the following fatal error:

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/26329A7C-04B0-415A-B8EB-3C59CC1EC0B1/hammerhead.app/hammerhead
  Reason: image not found

I am sure that my Phone has version 6.0 and is up to date. My deployment target is set to 6.0 in my project file and in my info.plist file. What should I do?

The problem seems to be with the AdSupport framework, which I put in my app so the new Facebook SDK (3.1) could function with iOS 6.

Comment: I also get this error while running on the Simulator for iOS 5.1

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS versions less than 6.0, you'll need to make AdSupport.framework, Social.framework, and Accounts.framework optionally-linked.

Please  have a look at the attached screenshot.

Cheers!!![image]

Comment: You deserve more likes, sir. Screenshot > text.

Answer (score 56):

Solved my own problem: Set the frameworks that are giving you problems to "Optional" instead of "Required" by going to the project file Summary and scrolling down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Same for CloudKit.framework on iOS 7 (it is for iOS8 only). Go to General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries, change CloudKit.framework to Optional.
Thanks VSN.

Comment: What will happen if I need iCloud in iOS7?