# Optional framework in xCode 4 project template

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I created a template for xcode 4 and included `FacebookSDK` in it. The problem is that some frameworks (AdSupport, Accounts) must be set as "optional" if you want to use sdk on iOS 5. How can I make them optional from `TemplateInfo.plist`. Or there can be another solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594070/dyld-library-not-loaded-different-behavior-for-6-0-simulator-6-0-device/12812450#12812450

refer image i have attached.... hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the frameworks with the `-weak_framework` prefix to your OTHER_LDFLAGS, like this:

```
<key>SharedSettings</key>
<dict>
<key>OTHER_LDFLAGS</key>
<string>-all_load -ObjC -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social</string>
<key>CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC</key>
<string>YES</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

See this image. It will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this before project creation..somewhere in template settings. So that frameworks would be already "optional" after project creation.